# Skipping over while statement

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I was having some trouble with a program where I am suppose to allow a user to enter any amount of numbers into a program until they do not want to anymore. The program then should calculate the average and maximum of the numbers inputed. Where did I go wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DataSet
{
    //Instance Variables
    private double newValue;
    private double sum;
    private int count;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    //Constructors
    public DataSet()
    {
      double newValue  = 0;
      double sum = 0;
      int count = 0;
    }

    public void run()
    {
    }

    public double getaddValueToSet()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        newValue = scan.nextDouble();
        count += 1;
        return newValue;
    }

    public double getSum()
    {
      sum += newValue;
      return sum;
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double average;
        average = sum/count;
        return average;
    }

    public double getMaximum()
    {
      double max=newValue;
      if(newValue >= max)
      {
        max = newValue;
      }
      return max;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
      String str;
      str = "Average: " + getAverage() + "\n" +
      "Maximum: " + getMaximum();
      return str;
    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataSetRunner
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
      String answer = "yes";
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


     {
      System.out.println("Do you want to enter another number?");
      answer = scan.next();
     }

     while(answer.equals("yes"))
     {
       DataSet d1 = new DataSet();
       double sum, number;


       d1.run();
       number = d1.getaddValueToSet();
       sum = d1.getSum();
       answer = scan.nextLine();

       System.out.println(d1);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Well, what is your program supposed to do?  What does it actually do?  What errors (if any) do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: there are many issues are going on in your code

Comment: Name a code block then break out of it.

Comment: Your question is too vague

Comment: @azurefrog There are not any errors when compiling. The only problem is after the user is prompted to enter a number, directly after they enter a number, it prints out the max/average. I was looking to get it to allow the user to enter multiple inputs until when the user was prompted with the question if they wanted to enter another number, and they said anything but yes, it would then give them the max/average of the numbers they inputed.

Comment: @HopeRunsDeep Then to be more specific, i'm asking how I can fix my program so that it allows the user to input multiple numbers, instead of it just asking once. With how my program is currently, it prompts the user once to enter a number, then prints out the average/max. I would like it so that it will continually ask the user to input a number until the user would like to stop this, and then calculate the average/max.

Comment: You should fix your indentation; that might help you see your errors.

Comment: As a note, this code as-is has nowhere in it to store what the max value is. You can't calculate that from the sum, or from the count. You need another `double max`, and then somewhere `if(newValue > max) {max = newValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataSet d1 = new DataSet();
    do {
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another number?");
        answer = scan.next();
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
            double sum, number;
            d1.run();
            number = d1.getaddValueToSet();
            sum = d1.getSum();
            answer = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println(d1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I got it to work, just had to move the S.O.P(d1) outside of the while so it would not print every time.